# RenderView in Symfony Command usage

Tags: symfony, render

How can I use $this->renderView inside a symfony Command (not inside a controller)? I new about the function "renderView" but what do I have to setup to use it wihtin a command?

Thank you in advance an regards

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your command class must extends the `ContainerAwareCommand` [abstract class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php) and then you can do:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render($view, $parameters);
```

When it comes to commands that extend `ContainerAwareCommand` the proper way to obtain the container is by `getContainer()` unlike in controller shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, this is how it works perfectly. Well, thanks for your reply!!

Comment: Just another Question about the Command: How can I access security.content in a Command? 

$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

this won't work so I stuck again :(

Comment: Maybe because `$this->get('security.context')->getToken() === null`

Comment: Hm oky, this might be becaus I call it by console. therefor noone must be logged in. Uhhh my fault. sorry and thx for the hint !!

Comment: I tried it but I got the error as "You have requested a non-existent service "templeting"."

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 4 I could not get `$this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render($view, $parameters);` to work.

I set the namespace use for `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand` and extended ContainerAwareCommand `class EmailCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand`

I get an exception thrown

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
      You have requested a non-existent service "templating".
```

For Symfony 4, this is the solution I came up with.

First I installed Twig.

```
composer require twig
```

Then created my own twig service.

```
<?php

# src/Service/Twig.php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class Twig extends \Twig_Environment {

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel) {
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($kernel->getProjectDir());

        parent::__construct($loader);
    }
}
```

Now my email command looks like this.

```
<?php

# src/Command/EmailCommand.php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface,
    App\Service\Twig;

class EmailCommand extends Command {

    protected static $defaultName = 'mybot:email';

    private $mailer,
            $twig;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, Twig $twig) {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure() {
        $this->setDescription('Email bot.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

        $template = $this->twig->load('templates/email.html.twig');

        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('emailbot@domain.com')
            ->setTo('someone@somewhere.com')
            ->setBody(
                $template->render(['name' => 'Fabien']),
                'text/html'
            );

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because services are private by default meaning removed during container compilation process thus not available afterwards. You can verify this by running `debug:container templating` command. You could inject the `EngineInterface` instead and you would end up with Twig wired automatically.

Comment: @Mike is there a way to make core services, by default not available to console, available?

Edit ( just saw you solution )

Comment: You mean make private services public? Sure, just [declare them public](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default) in your `services.yml` or such.

Comment: @Mike thank you for you time. I am having a hard time declaring templating as public. What is the templating name I should declare public in services.yml?

Comment: Have you tried with EngineInterface? If not declare it as alias of the `templating` service and declare public. However command as a service is a better approach. The class is easier to test.

Comment: Yes, I have tried EngineInterface. It shows up when calling debug:container but throws an exception when trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another one: rely on dependency injection, i.e. inject `ContainerInterface`

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

class SampleCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->templating = $container->get('templating');
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('app:my-command')
             ->setDescription('Do my command using render');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $data = retrieveSomeData();
        $csv = $this->templating->render('path/to/sample.csv.twig',
                                         array('data' => $data));
        $output->write($csv);
    }

    private $templating;
}
```

This relies on Symfony to inject the container, which in turn is used to retrieve either `templating` or `twig` or whatever you need for your custom command.

Comment: Using the `templating` service is deprecated since Symfony 4.2