# Is it possible to use twig template to generate php file with makerbundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, boilerplate

I'm creating a command to generate some boiler code using the MakerBundle and a twig template (template.twig.php ).
I went throught the MakerBundle code on github and i saw that they only use php for templating.

Is it possible to use a twig template to generate my boiler code with MakerBundle ? if so, how to render it ?

IS it possible to change the template location ? because I saw comment saying that the templates should only live in resources/skeleton in the make bundle folder.

Comment: just load the twig engine in your command to use templating  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114460/renderview-in-symfony-command-usage

Comment: @john I want to generate a php class file not a view.

Comment: Sure it should be possible, what have you tried so far for creating a custom Maker? Is something not working?